# Covariance of two summations

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

Let's assume i have a random variable $Z_1$ that is the sum of two independent variables $X_1$ and $Y_1$. So $$Z_1 = X_1 + Y_1$$.

I know that $Var(Z_1) = Var(X_1) + Var(Y_1)$, because X and Y are independent. Now I have $Z_2 = X_2 + Y_2$, where $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are not dependent but $X_1$ and $X_2$ and $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are dependent.

Is it true to say that $Cov(Z_1, Z_2) = Cov(X_1, X_2) + Cov(Y_1, Y_2)$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $X_1$ also independent from $Y_2,$ and the same for $X_2$ and $Y_1$?

Comment: yes. I may found the answer. as $Cov[X_1+Y_1, X_2+Y_2] =Cov[X_1,X_2] + Cov[Y_1,Y_2] + Cov[X1,Y_2] + Cov[Y_1, X_2]$ and because the last two terms are zero, my statement should be valid, i guess

Comment: Yep, that checks out.

Comment: You use the terminology "not dependent" and "dependent". It is more common (and IMV less confusing to go for "independent"and "not independent" instead.

Comment: Independence of $X_1,Y_2$ and $X_2,Y_1$ is relevant info and should be a part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

$$Cov[Z_1,Z_2]=\mathbb{E}[Z_1Z_2]-\mathbb{E}[Z_1]\mathbb{E}[Z_2]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_1Z_2]=\mathbb{E}[(X_1+Y_1)(X_2+Y_2)]=\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2+X_1Y_2+Y_1X_2+Y_1Y_2]$$
Since only $X_1,X_2$ and $Y_1,Y_2$ are dependent we end up with
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]+\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[Y_2]+\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]+\mathbb{E}[Y_1Y_2]$$
Now the second term of the covariance is
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_1]\mathbb{E}[Z_2]=\mathbb{E}[(X_1+Y_1)]\mathbb{E}[(X_2+Y_2)]=\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]+\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[Y_2]+\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]+\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\mathbb{E}[Y_2]$$
So in the end we get
$$Cov[Z_1,Z_2]=\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]-\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]+\mathbb{E}[Y_1Y_2]-\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\mathbb{E}[Y_2]=Cov[X_1,X_2]+Cov[Y_1,Y_2]$$

Comment: Sorry, but where in the question is it stated that $X_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent? The same question for $X_2$ and $Y_1$. I cannot find it.

Comment: @drhab Comments on OP

Answer (score 1):

Exploit that covariance is bilinear:

$$\mathsf{Cov}(X_1+Y_1,X_2+Y_2)=\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)+\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,Y_2)+\mathsf{Cov}(Y_1,X_2)+\mathsf{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)$$

In a comment you confirm that $X_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, and that $X_2$ and $Y_1$ are independent, so we can take out the second and third term. What remains is:$$\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)+\mathsf{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)$$

Eventual independence of $X_1,Y_1$ and/or $X_2,Y_2$ is irrelevant.